# In solr how do you maximize variability within a page of a result set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

This is for a product search where we want to show a variety of brands in the search results (24 per page).  Ideally we would limit it to each item on the page must have a unique brand id, unless given the page in the result set, that is impossible.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

what a great question! There's no simple answer, but you might want to try using the [grouping functionality](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) that Solr provides.  This would you give you one result per brand id that has matching results.  If you don't get enough results from that, you could fall back to the "regular" search results.  But I don't know of any way to distribute results evenly throughout your brands, because Solr results are ordered using a scoring mechanism where each result is scored independently.  Perhaps you could write a Scorer with some memory that would down-weight subsequent matches from previously-seen brands?

Comment: I think your idea to group by brand id is rather good. That way you may display the top notch hit of each brand group and you could decide to display the first 24 top hit groups.

Comment: We'll take a look at the grouping function and custom Scorers.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you can do in the Scorer, since the documents will come in essentially random order while scoring.  Perhaps you could imagine some kind of two-pass scoring, but you might as well do that in the client...